# The use of Spring framework in Java EE 6

Tags: java-ee-6, java-ee-5

I have been studying Java EE 6 and I want to ask, is Spring necessary when building Java EE 6? I learnt it is necessary in Java EE 5 but not in Java EE 6; is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is not a specification of Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE). It is a framework. You can use a particular version of Spring depending upon the Java EE version. We use Spring3.0 on Java EE 5 but it can also be used on Java EE 6. There is nothing stopping you using Spring based on a Java EE version.